# SQLAlchemy: ImportError: cannot import name Column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, importerror

I just get sqlalchemy with pip doing

```
pip install sqlalchemy
```

When I import a simple Class from sqlalchemy like this in a python console

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
```

I get this error

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "sqlalchemy.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Unicode, UnicodeText, String
ImportError: cannot import name Column
```

I have the same error on an OSX and an Ubuntu environment. 
On the SQLAlchemy website support section there is no references about this issues.
Is it something related to my Python environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You named your own script `sqlalchemy.py` or have another python file by that name in the same directory and it is masking the library. Rename that file.

You can see this in your traceback; the script imported *a local file* `sqlalchemy.py` (no path), which then tried to import itself again.

Comment: Wah! Solved! You saved my day! 
Thanx martijn

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column
```

[sqlalchemy.schema.Column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column)